# Do I lose my attack in Clash of clans war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I start a battle in a war, but click "end attack' before I attack, will this still count as one of my attacks in the war?

Comment: I'm not familiar to the game, but I think this is something you can try out yourself, and answer your own question!

Comment: @Mathias711: True, this is easily testable. However, when in a war, you  only get two attacks total. So, potentially wasting half of your available attacks "for science" isn't terribly fair to the rest of the people in your clan that you are playing along side. Personally, I would ask a question about it here before attempting it myself.

Comment: @Ellesedil Okay. That is why I stated that I am not familiar to the game. I had no idea of that

Answer (score 9):

No, as long as you don't place any units or spells you  can either skip or exit the attack screen completely.

Comment: I'm not sure.... since this is war and you're being asked if you really want to attack

Comment: I just went and tested it, he is correct

Comment: With the latest update, this is no longer true.

Answer (score 1):

I think since the last update you can not end the battle without loosing. I just did it to myself. I started the battle and realised I wanted to check the range of the dudes cc.  I hit end and bam I got 0 out of 3 stars and now only have one attack left. I also watched the replay. 19 seconds of nothing. No troops or spells deployed.

Comment: Excellent point. This has indeed changed, but only for war attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put a barb or anything else like a spell, you're good to go. Just make sure of the "Battle starts in: 20 secs" or anything. If it gets to zero, unless you wanna lose trophies like crazy, you gotta attack. Or BUSTED.

Comment: You can't lose trophies in clan war attacks.  Also, you won't lose trophies in non clan war attacks unless you place a unit or cast a spell, regardless of the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are doing a regular attack or if you attack during a war, you can exit without losing your attack/trophies as the condition that you did not deploy any single troop on the map.

This is something I personally experienced in a war, where I suddenly realized that I only had half of my troops available. I exited and I was still able to attack later on.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think so.**

There are two labels for Ending the game:

```
1: End Battle
2: Surrender
```

Of course, second one is not suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You will not lose. I have tried this personally a few weeks ago. As long as the 30 seconds doesn't run out, or you place any troops or spells, you will be fine. If you do accidentally drop in a spell or troops, or the timer runs out, you should just go through with the attack.

Good luck with your war and have fun! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you lose your attack, the people answering these questions don't know what they are talking about, today I lost a war raid because of this...